# under what conditions can the homotopy or homology functors be applied to a diagram of top spaces, while commutativity or exactness still holds?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a fibre sequence, a cofibre sequence, a pushout square, a pullback square or a commutative diagram (such as 3 object diagram depicting a retraction of a subspace), if I apply $\pi_k$ or $H_k$ to all spaces in the diagrams, which properties are preserved or induced? Also, is there any other type of sequence or diagram or else that can be useful in calculating homotopy and homology groups?

For example, I believe I can apply the homotopy functor to a fibre or cofibre sequence to get an exact sequence. I think I can apply $H_n$ to a commutative diagram and still get a commutative diagram.

I'm trying to figure out all the instances where I can apply one of these functors and keep commutativity or induce an exact sequence. My goal is usually to calculate all homotopy or homology groups of some space, knowing that the space fits into some commutative diagram or sequence.

Comment: Applying any functor to a commutative diagram gives a commutative diagram. This is essentially the definition of functor.

Comment: applying $\pi_*$ to a fibre sequence or $H_*$ to a cofibre sequence give long exact sequences, but computing $H_*$ of a fibre sequence in general involves [spectral sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sequence). If you have a retraction $A\stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} X \stackrel{r}{\to} A$ and a covariant functor $F$ then $F(r) \circ F(i) = id_{F(A)}$ so in particular if $F$ maps to a concrete category then $F(i)$ is injective and $F(r)$ is surjective.